# What is the word for "since beginning of time"?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have the word "eternal" that refers to something that will exist forever, something that never ends, which is related to the word "eternity" that refers to the end of time.

Is there a similar word for "the beginning of time", or something that has existed, as some might say, "since forever"? As an adjective, it would be used like: "My love for you is ...". The noun could be used like: "I have loved you since ...".

There is such a Persian word, for example, widely used in Persian literature, which is usually used to describe God, Love, etc.

Comment: Eternity does not  refer to the end of time. It something lasted only until the end of time, it wouldn't be eternal.

Answer (score 2):

Eternal does not refer to the "end of time." Eternal means "outside of time."

See [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eternal)

> 1Lasting or existing forever; without end or beginning:

Something that has existed "since forever"  is *eternal*. It is outside of time and did not have a beginning.

Consider the cosmos. If it did not have a beginning, but has always existed, then it is eternal. If it had a beginning, it has not existed forever.

> As an adjective, it would be used like: "My love for you is ...". The noun could be used like: "I have loved you since ...".

Adjective: *eternal*. 
My love for you is eternal.

Noun: Does not compute. 
You cannot use a 'time-word' such as "since" to refer to the eternal or eternity.
However, you may simply replace "since" with "for". "I have loved you for eternity."

You can refer to "the beginning of time". "In the beginning, God created...", or "In the beginning, the Uncaused Cause caused...".
  On the other hand, you can't refer to "(Before) the beginning of time", because time came into existence along with the cosmos. Outside of time stands eternity.

Comment: Yes. "Eternal" has both meanings. What I need, is to somehow distinguish between "having no beginning" and "having no end" in time. Maybe I should edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: This question is about a word or phrase that could be used for "since the beginning of time". It is not about the meaning of the adjective *eternal*. This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: As quoted by Alan from Oxford, "eternal" _can_ be used to mean that.

Comment: Leaning on statements like "outside of time" just causes confusion, and almost certainly can't be put to use here the way you'd like. If there are no points on the surface of a sphere north of the northernmost point, there are no points that are "outside" the surface of the sphere because they are in any way more, or less, northern. Words can point at concepts that don't exist or don't make sense.

Comment: +1 Came here to say eternal. "Timeless" is also a good choice.